# WordData for other languages

Tags: curated-data, linguistics

*Mathematica* already includes dictionaries for a lot of languages. What I am looking for is a handy semantic/grammatic database for Hungarian, just like `WordData` for English. Is it available in any form? Does Wolfram intend to include other languages into *Mathematica* in the future? Does anyone know anything about the trajectory WRI aims for concerning languages?

Comment: `WordData` is based on WordNet.  I am not aware of any comparable projects for Hungarian. Also a problem is that whenever someone makes a usable linguistic database, they tend to keep it private, even if they don't sell it for money ... it's really annoying.   If you do find anything, I'd appreciate if you could mail me :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs So far I have the exact same experience. For example I had to manually code inflectional rules for Hungarian from textbooks as there is no open-source database on the net. Maybe you are the only one here who can imagine how exceptionally irregular Hungarian is. Of course I won't share this code with anyone... :)

Comment: Since you asked the question in a general way, I'll just [link to a question about such a database for Chinese](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/793/is-there-a-chinese-wordnet).

Comment: For completeness, though it's an old post, I think it's relevant to mention LanguageData[] which has been introduced in mathematica 10
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LanguageData.html

Comment: Yeah, that would be fantastic, also for German, French, Spanish, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current references for WordData can be seen [online](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/note/WordDataSourceInformation.html).

If you would like to suggest an addition, there is a link where you can suggest additional functionality.

Answer (score 2):

A new project can be crawling websites to determine syntactic relationships.

Similarly here is a [romani database](http://romani.humanities.manchester.ac.uk/rms/) that may help (depending on what you're trying to do).